# Representing URL Queries in React Router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-router, react-router-v4

I've seen some other examples with different versions of React-Router (pre v4) but I can't seem to find a way to get URL parameters to be represented properly.

For example if I want to send a link to a friend from a search result it would look like:
https://yourwebsite.com/search?item-name=youritem

In this case I know that React-Router(v4) can provide optional parameters but they aren't represented in the URL so how would you be able to send that exact request to the server for the information.

i.e. I send the link above to a friend -> it hits the server then data gets populated in the component.

Comment: Are you asking how to pass and receive query params?

Comment: Rather, how can I build that URL using react-router v4. 
Right now most URLs I see are simple ones like yourweb.com/search/blah/blah

Comment: As in how to set up a `Route` to take queries?

Comment: Yeah that would be accurate. The flow i'm looking for is search -> get information from API -> return and change URL to reflect changes rendering new component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really is no special thing you have to do, just set up a `Route` like so:

```
<Route path="/search" component={MySearchComponent} />
```

This will set up the `/search` route. Then, to access whatever query parameters that are passed, in your `MySearchComponent`:

```
const queryParameters = this.props.location.search;
```

The [`location`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location) prop is passed to components via React Router. It contains the whole query string. So if I navigate to:

```
https://myWebsite.com/search?foo=bar&baz=buzz
```

Then `this.props.location.search` would be:

```
'?foo=bar&baz=buzz'
```

This is similar to [`Location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search) on modern browsers. Next, you can use a querystring parser library like the builtin [`querystring`](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) or any others in NPM, or even the browser's own [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams):

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(queryParameters);
const foo = params.get('foo'); //baz
const baz = params.get('baz'); //buzz
```

Do note that this is not supported on Internet Explorer. I'd recommend using an NPM library instead.

Comment: just to follow up on my question. So you're correct in that if I go like https://myWebsite.com/search?foo=bar&baz=buzz
 it'll be passed in. But lets say after I click on a search bar it goes to /search but will the parameters be reflected in the browser url as well?

Comment: @efxgamer What do you mean? Are you saying once you enter something into a search and click search you want the query params to reflect in the browser?

Comment: exactly. like if I enter search on something i'd like it to redirect with the query params reflected in the browser while the params are also passed into the component. maybe I wasn't clear originally I apologize.

Comment: @efxgamer You could use a `Link` component from React Router and include parameters. They should reflect in the URL IIRC. Or you could use the `withRouter` and push to history with the specific parameters. They should be reflected in the URL.